# bash or sh - bahow preserver line break and file structure when moving content from one file to another or edit the file in bash or sh

Tags: bash, sh

I have this file

I have this file named filename and the content is

```
export k="multiline_v"
```

for example

```
export k="kdk=dkdk
kdkdkdk=kdkd
ldldldsgg"
```

another example:

```
export k="-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIENjCCAx4CCQDQDy8tPglm1DANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBWMQswCQYDVQQDDAJD
QTENMAsGA1UECwwEU1NDRTENMAsGA1UECgwEU1NOQzEPMA0GA1UEBwwGRFVSSEFN
AQELBQADggEBAHgkLaegFG5CemXZfSocsaR/4zSbTgefgCTusrArUJGMO+2CNQRP
5lK9bXaXykyX7lJGsdZbS13Vy9sdQQVj0icW70bagIwl/p8mXbTzTgDdtCPsJLN7
uOkQRS646rp4nVEmp86imAgGWL+sdBG9WPhYsD0ZeDd28B6XBVMfm1k5DfPR9r6E
iigSB0hbPIlEbVpHQNsuHdpbKqGLjm4mNCpxdqjSMDNt9VjJAdjrZb7eQjuai95F
Vy9bwizvXDoE2pPJ056gkBYLS7nhS277lgs9Z+oLDa0bRFxw27pvNPvkaDv5dtyd
b/F+NL/Fe738KoZ3FO69Fl6GnNZiMOP50gc=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJQwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCCS0wggkpAgEAAoICAQDBi+FpwvWVTWbY
XN/zvjDJPOtffs3o6EuQAAhE5XAgfudar8gcojAegL9mU3owa5+s0w0Je9eWDkQt
XkxewcAfcKZ08vALmZhyI8w5+dJPTQqGug1aObF+W+hUezKr/l6nyfT8cbdP/gPT
Wp0wfm6yJUFaecUgYh8I3gvsJ5XaV5OHilNVzz53nYXCAdXmSyocwef51XWchJh0
EYKZzw0V6t0CLuCnbAcICjQ3GNP5HaZ8cfXkIGDqmTJM4UCDfAMG7mkv0O13+7uW
b9PnaQEZ175Aj27f+ke4w2q3Bd0BGNVkmc8bvqlL6Q9GUGJJcF6VSpNVNP/Royr+
yyOY18Zk20TB3wZC3RI4qh8eATkToHoEM+THRgsoUGesx4r4axWEz3Ud2NxN8elk
5O8ghWqmxnEdcXDtyA90Io7ZWRjP8pE=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

I use this to cut the name k

```
filename=myfile
key=$(head -n1 $filename | cut -d '=' -f 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
```

Then I want to have another file named k and the content be v without ""

In the examples above it is gonna be

```
kdk=dkdk
kdkdkdk=kdkd
ldldldsgg
```

and

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIENjCCAx4CCQDQDy8tPglm1DANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBWMQswCQYDVQQDDAJD
QTENMAsGA1UECwwEU1NDRTENMAsGA1UECgwEU1NOQzEPMA0GA1UEBwwGRFVSSEFN
AQELBQADggEBAHgkLaegFG5CemXZfSocsaR/4zSbTgefgCTusrArUJGMO+2CNQRP
5lK9bXaXykyX7lJGsdZbS13Vy9sdQQVj0icW70bagIwl/p8mXbTzTgDdtCPsJLN7
uOkQRS646rp4nVEmp86imAgGWL+sdBG9WPhYsD0ZeDd28B6XBVMfm1k5DfPR9r6E
iigSB0hbPIlEbVpHQNsuHdpbKqGLjm4mNCpxdqjSMDNt9VjJAdjrZb7eQjuai95F
Vy9bwizvXDoE2pPJ056gkBYLS7nhS277lgs9Z+oLDa0bRFxw27pvNPvkaDv5dtyd
b/F+NL/Fe738KoZ3FO69Fl6GnNZiMOP50gc=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJQwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCCS0wggkpAgEAAoICAQDBi+FpwvWVTWbY
XN/zvjDJPOtffs3o6EuQAAhE5XAgfudar8gcojAegL9mU3owa5+s0w0Je9eWDkQt
XkxewcAfcKZ08vALmZhyI8w5+dJPTQqGug1aObF+W+hUezKr/l6nyfT8cbdP/gPT
Wp0wfm6yJUFaecUgYh8I3gvsJ5XaV5OHilNVzz53nYXCAdXmSyocwef51XWchJh0
EYKZzw0V6t0CLuCnbAcICjQ3GNP5HaZ8cfXkIGDqmTJM4UCDfAMG7mkv0O13+7uW
b9PnaQEZ175Aj27f+ke4w2q3Bd0BGNVkmc8bvqlL6Q9GUGJJcF6VSpNVNP/Royr+
yyOY18Zk20TB3wZC3RI4qh8eATkToHoEM+THRgsoUGesx4r4axWEz3Ud2NxN8elk
5O8ghWqmxnEdcXDtyA90Io7ZWRjP8pE=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

If I could copy the file and find a command to do it in place, it would be great because the file would not change and the part I want to keep (the right side of the first = sign in  the first line and all the other lines except the last ") would remain untouched, I would prefer to do this.

I think it is not possible. That is why I have to somehow copy and process it.
How to do it such that everything stays untouched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input:

```
$ cat f1
export k="kdk=dkdk
kdkdkdk=kdkd
ldldldsgg"
```

Three easy steps:

```
IFS='=' read -r exp_var stuff < f1                  # read 1st line, use '=' as delimiter;
                                                    # place first field in variable 'exp_var';
                                                    # place rest of line in variable 'stuff'

fname="${exp_var#* }"                               # strip off leading 'export ' leaving 'k'

sed '1s/^[^"]*"//; $s/"[^"]*$//' f1 > "${fname}"    # 1s == 1st line, strip off everything up to first '"'
                                                    # $s == last line, strip off last '"' and anything after it (eg, white space, \r)
```

This generates:

```
$ cat k
kdk=dkdk
kdkdkdk=kdkd
ldldldsgg
```

Assuming file `f1` is OP's original certificate file the above 3-lines of code generate:

```
$ cat k
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIENjCCAx4CCQDQDy8tPglm1DANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBWMQswCQYDVQQDDAJD
QTENMAsGA1UECwwEU1NDRTENMAsGA1UECgwEU1NOQzEPMA0GA1UEBwwGRFVSSEFN
AQELBQADggEBAHgkLaegFG5CemXZfSocsaR/4zSbTgefgCTusrArUJGMO+2CNQRP
5lK9bXaXykyX7lJGsdZbS13Vy9sdQQVj0icW70bagIwl/p8mXbTzTgDdtCPsJLN7
uOkQRS646rp4nVEmp86imAgGWL+sdBG9WPhYsD0ZeDd28B6XBVMfm1k5DfPR9r6E
iigSB0hbPIlEbVpHQNsuHdpbKqGLjm4mNCpxdqjSMDNt9VjJAdjrZb7eQjuai95F
Vy9bwizvXDoE2pPJ056gkBYLS7nhS277lgs9Z+oLDa0bRFxw27pvNPvkaDv5dtyd
b/F+NL/Fe738KoZ3FO69Fl6GnNZiMOP50gc=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJQwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCCS0wggkpAgEAAoICAQDBi+FpwvWVTWbY
XN/zvjDJPOtffs3o6EuQAAhE5XAgfudar8gcojAegL9mU3owa5+s0w0Je9eWDkQt
XkxewcAfcKZ08vALmZhyI8w5+dJPTQqGug1aObF+W+hUezKr/l6nyfT8cbdP/gPT
Wp0wfm6yJUFaecUgYh8I3gvsJ5XaV5OHilNVzz53nYXCAdXmSyocwef51XWchJh0
EYKZzw0V6t0CLuCnbAcICjQ3GNP5HaZ8cfXkIGDqmTJM4UCDfAMG7mkv0O13+7uW
b9PnaQEZ175Aj27f+ke4w2q3Bd0BGNVkmc8bvqlL6Q9GUGJJcF6VSpNVNP/Royr+
yyOY18Zk20TB3wZC3RI4qh8eATkToHoEM+THRgsoUGesx4r4axWEz3Ud2NxN8elk
5O8ghWqmxnEdcXDtyA90Io7ZWRjP8pE=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 2):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code demonstrates one possible way to do what you want:

```
#! /bin/sh -

filename=$1

sh -c ' fake_export()
        {
            printf "%s\\n" "${1#*=}" >"${1%%=*}"
        }

        alias export=fake_export

        . "$1"
    ' sh "$filename"
```

Save it to a file (e.g. `myprog`), make it executable (`chmod +x myprog`) and test it with `./myprog ./myfile` (where `myfile` contains `export k="..."`).

- The avoids all the intricacies of shell quote removal by letting the shell do it.
- The basic idea is to source the `export ...` file, but make the shell use a special function (`fake_export`) instead of the real `export`.  POSIX shell doesn't allow a function with the name `export` to be defined, so the code uses an alias instead.  (This would not work with `bash` as it is because `bash` disables aliases in non-interactive code by default.)
- When something like `export k="x y z"` is executed, `fake_export` is run with argument `k=x y z` (because the shell removes the quotes before calling it) so it can easily separate out the key and value by just splitting on the (first) `=`.

Comment: TIL that since issue 7, aliases have been part of the POSIX baseline standard, vs the User Portability Utilities annex.